# Exchange Time Capsule hard drive with PS4 Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-capsule

is it from the data and values possible, to exchange the PS4 and Time Capsule's Hard Drive?
So built in the PS4 the Time Capsule hard drive and in the Time Capsule the PS4 Hard Drive.
Could anyone say me if it so possible and works fine?

Comment: To you expand your question to tell us why you want to do this? Are you just wanting a larger drive in your PS4?

Comment: @Alistair McMillan Yes, I thought before I buy I new hard drive, I could only exchange them, because my time capsule has 2 TB storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to put the PS4 drive in the Time Capsule but not vice versa, and not really recommended.

According to [this support document](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/Upgrade-PS4-HDD/) from Sony, the PS4 uses a 2.5" hard drive.

According to iFixit guides such as this one for [the pizza box model](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Apple+Time+Capsule+Model+A1302+Hard+Drive+Replacement/2750) and this one for [the newer vertical model](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/AirPort+Time+Capsule+A1470+%28Mini%21%29+Teardown/15067) the Apple Time Capsule uses 3.5" drives.

So, with an adapter, the Time Capsule drive could work in the PS4, but the PS4 drive won't fit in the Time Capsule.